# ¿Como personalizar mi JComboBox?

Tags: java

Quiero cambiar el diseño del JComboBox pero no hayo la manera, en Google aparecen muy pocos videos pero ninguno que me lo solucione, quiero cambiar de lugar la flecha, quitarle el borde del combo para que parezca que esta mezclado con el panel, y ponerle a la flechita un nuevo diseño/imagen Y la verdad no se si eso se pueda, alguna sugerencia?

```
Dificultad = new JComboBox();
Dificultad.setBounds(12, 12, 123, 24);
Dificultad.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(51, 255, 255));
Dificultad.addItem("Contra un amigo");        
Dificultad.addItem("Facil");
Dificultad.addItem("Medio");
Dificultad.addItem("Dificil");
Dificultad.setFocusable(false);
Dificultad.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
      public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                
      }
});
PanelPuntaje.add(Dificultad);
```

Comment: No se si eso eso se pueda, y la verdad lo necesito saber urgentemente, **asi sea una pista, yo investigo por mi cuenta**

Comment: En [este sitio](https://www.codejava.net/java-se/swing/create-custom-gui-for-jcombobox) explican como personalizar un JComboBox, aunque no con el nivel de detalle que deseas

Comment: con solo que me orienten, yo sabria defenderme, pero no se por donde empezar ya que no encuentro nada en google

Comment: El JDK es de código abierto. Para comprender cómo se escribe un componente Swing, no hay mejor lugar para buscar que el código fuente de los componentes Swing. Por ejemplo, [en esta pregunta de SO en inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3008447/how-can-i-change-the-arrow-style-in-a-jcombobox) explican cómo modificar la flecha. Quizá te sirva como referencia para las otras cosas que deseas hacer.

Comment: no amigo, eso tampoco me lo explica bien (el link), y lo busque ahora en la página de inglés de stack overflow pero igual, es tan dificil?